# Counting total number of variables in a np.array

Tags: python

I have a dataset, within that dataset a column specifying the Location as States.

I am using jupyter notebook, numpy only.

The dataset is in an array.

I wanted to remove the duplicate states so I can count the number of states I have in the column.

I have to use `np.unique`.

Could you help me in how I can go about writing a code to find out the number of states I have? Removing the duplicates and just the total of states.

Thanks

Comment: len(np.unique(arr)) will give you the number of unique values in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location = dataset[:,2] #or whatever column you're selecting for location
np.unique(location)
```

Hope your states are numbers and not words

Comment: Thanks Diana. The states are words. How would that change things?

Comment: @Nathan it should actually work anyway, try it out. I've always just seen examples with integers but your whole array would consist of strings so it should be fine

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it. So it is listing my entire array, each state. How would I go about adding the total of those words, to count it?

Comment: What do you mean adding the total of the words? As in the total number of words, example 10, and then adding 1+2+3...+10? Or do you just want to know how many words the array has? In the second case, let's say A =  np.unique(location), len(A) should work